# How to show the value in HTML with PHP echo

Tags: php

Please help me.
I have a problem to show the value in html with echo in PHP

Here is my coding.

```
<input type="text" value ="123" id="addorderquantity[<?php echo $count - 1; ?>]" name="quantity[<?php echo $count - 1; ?>]" onChange="addordercalculate(<?php echo $count - 1; ?>)">
```

At the input box, the value was always show "0" even i already set it to "123"

But if i write the id to "`addorderquantity[<?php echo $count; ?>]`" (without minus 1)
The value can work correctly.

This is the all of the code

```
<?php
                    $queryorder = "select * from orderitem,product where (orderitem.productid = product.productid) and orderitem.orderid = '$orderid' and orderitem.actype != 'D'";
                    $resultorder = mysql_query($queryorder);
                    $count  = 1;
                    while ($order = mysql_fetch_array($resultorder)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="addordercategory[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="category[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" onChange="loadproduct(<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>)">
                                <option></option>
                                <?php
                                    for($i=0; $i<count($datacategorys)-1; $i++){
                                        $data1 = explode ("||",$datacategorys[$i]);
                                        if ($order['category'] == $data1[0]){
                                            echo "<option value='$data1[0]' selected>$data1[1]</option>";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo "<option value='$data1[0]'>$data1[1]</option>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="addorderproduct[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="product[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" onChange="loadpriceweight(<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>)">
                                    <?php
                                        $queryproduct = "select * from product where category = '".$order['category']."' and actype != 'D'";
                                        $resultproduct = mysql_query($queryproduct);
                                        while ($product = mysql_fetch_array($resultproduct)){
                                            if ($order['productid'] == $product['productid']){
                                                echo "<option value='".$product['productid']."' selected='selected'>".$product['name']."</option>";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                echo "<option value='".$product['productid']."'>".$product['name']."</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <script type="text/javascript">loadpriceweight(<?php echo ($count - 1);?>);</script>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" id="addorderprice[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="price[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="0">
                                <input type="text" id="addorderdisprice[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" disabled="disabled" value="">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" id="addorderweight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="weight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="0">
                                <input type="text" id="addorderdisweight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" disabled="disabled" value="0">
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="text" value ="123" id="addorderquantity[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="quantity[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" onChange="addordercalculate(<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>)"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="addorderdiscount[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="discount[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="0" onChange="addordercalculate(<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>)"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="addorderdistotprice[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" disabled="disabled" value="0"><input type="hidden" id="addordertotprice[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="totprice[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="0"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="addorderdistotweight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" disabled="disabled" value="0"><input type="hidden" id="addordertotweight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" name="totweight[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="0"></td>
                            <td><input type="button" id="addorderhapus[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]" value="hapus" onClick="addorderhapus(<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <script type="text/javascript">addordercount = <?php echo $count;?>;</script>
                        <?php
                        $count++;
                    }
                ?>
```

Please help me, Thank you very much.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. Explain your functions or add more code.

Comment: Please proofread this question. And make sure you read the FAQ:http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I don't see it as your problem, but you should close your input tag. <input type='text' .... />. Is there any javascript (other than the onchange) affecting this element? What's this line look like in the 'view source' window?

Comment: please see it again, i already add my code again.
i already test to put <input ... /> but it's still not working too.

Comment: Please note: the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and in the process of being deprecated. Please see the notes in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for confirmation of this. You are **strongly recommended** to switch to using either the newer `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 3):

This code should work, have you tried putting round-brackets around `$count - 1` (`<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>`)?

Comment: It's Still not working, friend.
Do you have another idea?
Anyway, Thank you very much, friend.

Comment: I think it will be beneficial if you elaborate a bit more on your question though. Or maybe do a var_dump() of $count at least.

Comment: i already test to use var_dump() for the $count value. and it's show int(1), int(0). That's value was already right, friend. :)
Now, i don't know what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have noted in your update that you explicitly set `$count` to 1:

```
...
$resultorder = mysql_query($queryorder);
$count  = 1;
while ($order = mysql_fetch_array($resultorder)){
...
```

This will cause it to be 0 if you subtract 1?

Comment: yes, friend. that's will show the right value. the problem is, if i make arithmetic operation in naming the id, the value will set to 0. but i not make any arithmetic operation, i can set the value.

Comment: This might mean that your SQL query isn't returning the rows you expect it to return.

Comment: the SQL can looping as the data in database correctly. The problem just i want to make the quantity value in the input box as the value in database. but i can not set the value.

Comment: Ok, so everything works as it should except for the value of the input box, named "quantity[<?php echo ($count - 1); ?>]"? From your example you set the value to 123. Shouldn't this value be something like 'value="<?php $product['quantity'] ?>"', if it's from the DB right?

Comment: Sorry, it just feels like I'm not understanding your code clearly :)